An iterative plot is not drawn in jupyter notebook while python works fine. Why?
I have written an iterative plot code for python using plt.draw(). While it works fine for python interpreter and ipython also, but it does not work in jupyter notebook. I am running python in virtualenv in Debian. The codes are
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

N=5
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for n in range(N):
    y = np.sin(np.pi*x*n)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    line.remove()

This works fine in command line such as

$ python a.py

But, in jupyter notebook, it plots first figure and then, repeat <Figure size ... 0 Axes> for N-1 times, not drawing the new figure inside axis. It looks the problem of jupyter, because no problem in running python code. How can I fix this? Or plotly would work in jupyter? (N.B. I happen to find a jupyter community site and posted there also.)


Same content posted without linking here. Please don't post without linking all similar posts. That way others have the full view of what have been said and don't end up repeating each other. The other issue can be that those following in your footsteps with the same issue may find one post but not know the solution is over on another. (That phenomenon is sometimes referenced as 'creating information silos'.)

@Wayne: That's right. Both are the same. I have posted this issue here and while I browse several sites, I happen to find that site. Posting this in other site, I have thought about that you commented. Thank you for your guideline.

Jupyter Notebook handles plot display differently. If you’re able to modify the code, you can try the following approach:
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Parameters for the plot
N = 5
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)  # Line object

# Set the limits for the axes
ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

# Initialization function: called at the start
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# Update function: called for each frame
def update(n):
    y = np.sin(np.pi * x * n)  # Calculate sine wave
    line.set_data(x, y)        # Update line data
    return line,

# Create the animation using FuncAnimation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=N, init_func=init, blit=True, interval=500)

This method works well for me in VSCode.
If you want more control over the animation, you can display it directly in the Jupyter Notebook using:
# Display the animation in the Jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())  # Render the animation as HTML/JS


The frames parameter specifies the data passed to the update(n) function during each interaction step. Setting frames=N is equivalent to using frames=range(N). This operates similarly to the following loop:
for n in range(N):
    update(n)

For more details about FuncAnimation, please refer to the documentation at: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html.

It would be more explicit to use %matplotlib ipympl as it makes it clearer to users that to use it they need to install & use ipmypl these days. The basic example here in the ipympl documentation makes it clear that %matplotlib widget is still supported though. It is a leftover intermediate option from before the dust settled.

@SB: I get "Jupyter is different" and your solution which says move to animation. Though this is enough solution at the moment, I need to ask about animation flow chart because I can hardly find those explanations. QA: 'frames=N ' means update() is called N time? QB: How 'n' is set without pass argument and not coded n += 1?

@JoonhoPark Please see updated version of answer.

@SB: Now it is very obvious and your statement with example is better than obscure formal linked document.
